# Como instalar biblioteca no Raspberry sem internet?

Tags: biblioteca, raspberry-pi

Tenho um Raspberry pi 3 sem acesso a internet e preciso instalar nele a biblioteca RPI.GPIO, tenho como baixar de outra máquina e passar a biblioteca por pendrive. As minhas dúvidas são: Em que pasta coloco a biblioteca e que comando eu uso para instalar esta biblioteca?

Comment: Olá Matheus, em relação a `Raspberry Pi`, tente perguntar no [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), acho que por ser voltado para a mesma é mais fácil de encontrar sua resposta lá. Além disso, pela questão não ser específica para Raspberry, tente perguntar no [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode baixar o pacote referente a biblioteca que você quer utilizar,no Github por exemplo, e utilizar o comando pip install e encontrar o arquivo localmente no seu dispositivo.

Exemplo:

*pip install ./downloads/SomeProject-1.0.4.tar.gz*

Caso tiver alguma dúvida quando a sintaxe, dá uma olhada na documentação sobre isso:

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-local-archives